# To print the frequency of the elements in an array, I have solved but facing some print issues. Help to resolve

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, frequency, array-algorithms

https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/cp-tutorial/challenges/cp-tutorial-11/problem

Below is my solution but the problem I am having is that the output prints the statement exactly the number of times the element is repeated instead of once for each distinct element. Can somebody help me out with this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  int a[1000005];

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> a[i];

  sort(a, a + n);
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
      if (a[j] == a[k]) {
        count = count + 1;
      }
    }

    if (count == 1) {
      cout << a[j] << " appears once in the array." << '\n';
    }
    if (count > 1) {
      cout << a[j] << " appears " << count << " times in the array." << '\n';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any aversion to using `std::vector`?  The size of the array is a lot to place on the stack.  Remember, stack is primarily used for passing variables and return addresses.  Large data structures should be declared `static` either in the function or as global.  The `std::vector` places the elements in dynamic memory.

Comment: BTW, if `count` is zero, nothing is output.

Comment: In C++ it is good practice to use modern arrays. Use `std::vector` for dynamic sized arrays or `std::array` for static stack allocated arrays. Do not use plain C-style arrays unless you need to communicate with the C code base.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your last two `if` statements with this. I believe it should work.

```
if (j + 1 == n || a[j] != a[j + 1]) {
  cout << a[j] << " appears ";
  if (count == 1)
    cout << "once in the array.\n";
  else
    cout << count << " times in the array.\n";
}
```

Update:

Your algorithm currently is O(n^2). We can take advantage of the fact that the array is sorted and count while doing a single pass:

```
sort(a, a + n);
int count = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
  count++;
  if (j + 1 == n || a[j] != a[j + 1]) {
    /* same code as above */
    count = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution is not efficient. The array is already sorted, but the guy still uses O(n^2) algorithm.

Comment: @AlexMaystrenko Yes I know. I was thinking he just wanted to fix the bug in the code he wrote and wasn't asking for a more efficient implementation.

Comment: @AlexMaystrenko Updated with O(n log n) program.

Comment: thanks, It worked perfect. I'd like to know how you implemented the time complexity so effeciently. Could you help me with resources? I am eager to learn it.

Comment: @Shakeeb I would recommend a good book as well as practice. A book I use is called [The Algorithm Design Manual](https://www.amazon.com/Algorithm-Design-Manual-Steven-Skiena/dp/1849967202). Also, sites like [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/) have been a great help for me in practicing algorithm problems.